# List cell load animation one after another in SwiftUI

Tags: animation, swiftui, swiftui-list, hstack

I need to animate the load of the List rows. When the list reloads the data I need the rows get in from the left one after another. How can I achieve this?

[image: Load list cell one after one with animation]

Comment: have you found solution to this ? Thanks

Comment: @mentoxska  yes i implement by myself.